# Node.js Express postgres stream data to response

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, stream, response

I am using **Node.js Express** with postgres db for some data displaying and I've built an api that gives me data in CSV format. In order to achieve optimal solution, I'm using streams. So I just used [pg.Pool](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool), [pg-query-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-query-stream) and basically use the code shown as example:

```
    pg.connect((err, client, done) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          const query = new QueryStream('SELECT * FROM table')
          const stream = client.query(query)
          //release the client when the stream is finished
          stream.on('end', done)
          stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res)
    })
```

Only difference between this and an example is that I stream to the response instead of process.stdout.

This solution worked fine, but I have noticed, that sometimes the client is not returned to the pool and hang in the database forever. 
I did some testing and found out, that when I create multiple queries to the API (refreshing page F5,... ), *response stream* is (somehow) destroyed before *client.query stream* finishes writing and therefore *stream.on('end', done)* never happens.
In the moment my solution is, that I release the client not when the writing stream is done, but when response stream closes, as below.

```
    pg.connect((err, client, done) => {
          if (err) throw err;

          //***NEW CODE***
          res.on('close', function() {
              stream.destroy();
              done();
          });

          const query = new QueryStream('SELECT * FROM table')
          const stream = client.query(query)
          //release the client when the stream is finished
          //stream.on('end', done)
          stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res)
    })
```

All I wanted to know, if this is standard solution for standard problem, or is this not a good and potentially dangerous practice.

Thanks for your comments.

step

Versions:

"node": "12.16.1"
"pg": "^8.0.0",
"pg-pool": "^3.0.0",
"pg-query-stream": "^3.0.4",
"express": "~4.16.0"

Comment: It's a dangerous practice, as you do not even handle errors correctly. Maybe [pg-iterator](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-iterator) can offer a safer approach?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I started using slonik (https://github.com/gajus/slonik) to avoid unsafe connection handling.